# Set state of other component from Formik's Error component

Tags: reactjs, formik, use-state

I have a code which overrides Formik's Error component which looks like:

```
const [ message, setMessage ] = useState("");    

const Error = props => {
        const fieldSelected = props.field;
        if ((errors[fieldSelected] && touched[fieldSelected])) {
            setMessage("");
            return (
                <span className={props.class ? props.class : "error-msg"}>
                    {errors[fieldSelected]}
                </span>
            );
        } else {
            return <span />;
        }
    };
```

Which should to set state of successful massage as `setMessage("")`. It works as expected but throws a warning:

> cannot update a component from inside the function body of a different component

I thought I can do callbacks but looks like I have done it wrong way.

Any tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

It came up there are two ways to do not display the message component if you have errors.

```
{!Object.keys(errors).length &&  <Message message={message}/>}
```

Other possibility is to reset the message exactly when you get the errors

```
function resetAPI(url, props, setMessage) {

    axios.post(url)
    .then(response => {
        setMessage("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
       setMessage('');
          ...
        }
    });
}
```

Hope that solves the issue.